# Change the div's css style in <aura:iteration>

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system, css

I have a component:

```
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.objects}" var="obj">     
        <lightning:layout multipleRows="true" class="layoutBigCardsColumn">
            <div class="slds-panel__body">
                <p><b>{!obj.Name}</b></p>
                <p>
                    <span class="spanButtonToResults">
                        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:chevrondown" onclick="{!c.show}" />
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p>{!obj.Location__c}</p>
            </div>
                <br/>
                <div aura:id="divId">
                    <p><b>Detailed INFO about {!obj.Name}</b></p>
                </div>
        </lightning:layout>
    </aura:iteration>
```

show function doesn't work:

```
show : function(component, event, helper) {
    var cmpTarget = component.find('divId');
    $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'divShow');
}
```

My css:

```
.THIS .divShow {
    color: red;
}
```

I understand that `<aura:id>` works in iteration wrong. But how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to know which element you need, so that means using indexVar:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.objects}" var="obj" indexVar="index">
    <lightning:layout multipleRows="true" class="layoutBigCardsColumn">
        <div class="slds-panel__body" data-index="{!index}">
        ...
```

And then you find the component you're looking for:

```
var infos = component.find("divId"),
    // Get the index value
    index = event.target.closest("[data-index]").dataset.index;
// Normalize to array
infos = infos.length? infos: [infos];
$A.util.addClass(infos[index], 'divShow');
```

`find` works in the following way: if there are no elements, return undefined, if 1 element, return the element, otherwise return an array. This is a consistent, defined behavior.